# How do I setup Eclipse for the Mac?

Tags: eclipse, macos

How do I setup Eclipse for the Mac? It says that I need the Java SDK, but when I go to Oracle's site I don't see OS X in the list of operation systems.

Comment: The JDK is distributed with OS X.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to install the JDK on OSX. Just download the Eclipse installer for Mac OSX. It works for my Mac out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to say it was already present on my Mac (I've been running Eclipse for a while; Java came pre-installed), but I'm still running OSX 10.5 and it looks like [Apple has given Java the boot](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Java/JavaSnowLeopardUpdate3LeopardUpdate8RN/NewandNoteworthy/NewandNoteworthy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010380-CH4-DontLinkElementID_2): :-(

> **Java Deprecation**
>
> As of the release of Java for Mac OS X 10.6 Update 3, the Java runtime ported by Apple and that ships with Mac OS X is deprecated. Developers should not rely on the Apple-supplied Java runtime being present in future versions of Mac OS X.
>
> The Java runtime shipping in Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard, and Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard, will continue to be supported and maintained through the standard support cycles of those products.

If you're running a Mac prior to the deprecated version, see the link and it talks about the location on your hard drive.

---

**UPDATE:** whew, looks like there's hope after all:

http://www.apple.com/pr/library/2010/11/12openjdk.html

> Apple also confirmed that Java SE 6 will continue to be available from Apple for Mac OS X Snow Leopard® and the upcoming release of Mac OS X Lion. Java SE 7 and future versions of Java for Mac OS X will be available from Oracle.

Java downloads available here:

- [Java 1.6](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572)
- [Java 1.7](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_mac.xml)
- [Java 1.8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Answer (score 1):

JDK comes by default with OS X, you should have JDK 6 already.

Go to your Eclipse -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs.

If nothing is listed there, then click on Search button. That should locate all the JREs.

Here's mine:-

[image: JRE]

By the way, I'm running Snow Leopard, if that helps any. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you have the right version of Eclipse and that your Mac is configured to have the correct SDK as the default; if you go to Finder > Applications > Utilities > Java Preferences, you can see which versions of Java are installed and select which one will be automatically selected; using 32-bit versions of Eclipse with the 64-bit one selected or vice-versa probably won't work very well.